# My rig does not move

Tags: rigging

I made a crude dinosaur model and added a rig to it and got the bones to move with the mesh. I went back to an earlier save and improved the dinosaur and followed the same procedure but now neither the bones or the mesh will move. Any ideas?

Comment: Please upload .blend file to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a very bad idea to rig something and then go back and change it. New vertices you create will not be assigned to any particular vertex group and new bones you create will not modify any new vertex groups, you'd have to take care of that using the weight paint tool or selecting "assign" in the vertex groups panel, or both. Do you have a blender file we can look at?